# Checked a checkbox on page refresh

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I'm trying to keep a checkbox checked, but after I refresh the page, database is update with satus '1' but on front-end checkboxes is unchecked, hope somebody can help.
Here is my code

```
<td>
   <span>
     <input type='checkbox' name='Id' value='".$checkSubRow['Checklist_Id']."' class='check' id='Completed-".$checkSubRow['Checklist_Id']."' onClick='Completed(".$checkSubRow['Checklist_Id'].")' 
            />
         echo (isset($_POST['checkbox']))? "checked='checked'": "";
 </span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 4):

the `name=Id` is what you will need to check. So change the `$_POST['checkbox']` to `$_POST['Id']`

Answer (score 1):

I think there one issue that the `echo (isset($_POST['checkbox']))? "checked='checked'": "";` is not inside the input tag. So, it wont apply to the tag. Also, the name should be used in the `$_POST['checkbox']` like `$_POST['Id']`

e.g.

```
    <td>
   <span>
     <input type='checkbox' name='Id' value='".$checkSubRow['Checklist_Id']."' class='check' id='Completed-".$checkSubRow['Checklist_Id']."' onClick='Completed(".$checkSubRow['Checklist_Id'].")'  <php echo (isset($_POST['Id']))? "checked='checked'": ""; ?>/>

 </span>
</td>
```

Try it out.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find solution for that so i changed it littile bit. here is revised code.

```
while ($checkSubRow = $checkSub->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{       
    if($checkSubRow['Status'])
    {
        $checked = "checked";
    } 
    else
    {
        $checked = "";
    }
    echo "<tr>
            <td>
<span><input type='checkbox' name='Id' class='check' id='Completed-".$checkSubRow['Checklist_Id']."' $checked onClick='Completed(".$checkSubRow['Checklist_Id'].")' /></span>
            </td>
```